# For a datepicker, why does one code snippet work, but the other doesn't?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want to populate two date fields on the same form, using "Today's date".

Both fields are read-only, to force the user to use the datepicker.

I can populate the first date field without problem.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="">
<div id="EffectiveFrom$CalendarBehavior_today" class="ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
@browser.div(:id => 'EffectiveFrom$CalendarBehavior_today', :class => 'ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today').click
```

---

Second date field

HTML:

```
<div class="">
<div id="RegistrationDate$CalendarBehavior_today" class="ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today">
    Today: July 15, 2014
</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
@browser.div(:id => 'RegistrationDate$CalendarBehavior_today', :class => 'ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today').click
```

The error is "Element not visible". But I can see exactly the same popup for the second field as I do for the first field.

(Edited) The popup that caused the "Element not visible" error message is fully displayed within the browser boundaries.

It seems to me (a non-techie) that the only difference between the first HTML and the second HTML is that the second HTML has inner text.

Comment: It sounds like the elements are in popups. Given the exception, are you sure the popup is being displayed before you try to click it?

Comment: @Justin. Post edited. Popup fully visible.

Comment: When I said the "are you sure the popup is being displayed", I was thinking more along the lines of a timing issue. I was envisioning you click something to trigger the popup to display, Watir tries to click the div and then the DOM gets updated to display the popup. Given that Watir tries to click the div before it gets displayed, you get the element not visible exception. Perhaps try a `@browser.div(:id => 'RegistrationDate$CalendarBehavior_today', :class => 'ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today').when_present.click`

Comment: I tried your exact code. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element not visible exception means that the element exists on the page but is not displayed (eg has a `style="display:none"`). Given that you can see the popup, it is likely a timing issue.

What happens is:

1. You click something to trigger the popup to display.
2. Watir tries to click the div element.
3. The browser finishes updating the popup's style such that it is now visible.

Given that Watir tries to click the div before it gets displayed, you get the element not visible exception.

You can tell Watir to wait for the element to become visible before trying to interact with it:

```
@browser.div(:id => 'RegistrationDate$CalendarBehavior_today', :class => 'ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today').when_present.click
```

Comment: I'm marking @justin's answer as correct, because it summarizes everything in a single answer. But it leaves a big question unanswered - as follows. With me, there's no such thing as "unattended test". Everything is done in debug mode in my IDE. I set breakpoints and wait for them to be hit. I set a breakpoint immediately after the command that launches the datepicker: `@browser.text_field(:id, "RegistrationDate").click` I then press F8 to step over. The delay in pressing F8 must seem like a million kiloyears to my i5 CPU. So, what difference does `when_present` make?

Comment: Maybe the breakpoint causes everything to be frozen - as if the breakpoint never happened. If this is a new question, let me know, and I'll post the new question.

Comment: So you are saying that you have manually waited for the popup to appear and then executed the click on the RegistrationDate? In that case, I would not expect `when_present` to make a difference since the element would already be present. Just to see if the `when_present` is doing anything, what happens if you do a `puts @browser.div(:id => 'RegistrationDate$CalendarBehavior_today', :class => 'ajax__calendar_footer ajax__calendar_today').present?` right before the line that does the `when_present.click`?

Comment: puts showed "true".I rolled back my RB to the date and time before my first post above. Everything works fine. I can't reproduce the failure by advancing my RB step by step to the latest version. So I think I've wasted a lot of your time. I apologize. I think I experienced a similar timing problem previously that was actually caused by a breakpoint on that line, and disappeared when the breakpoint was removed.

Comment: For the cleanliness of StackOverflow I would suggest you delete the question. Given we cannot reproduce the issue I do not think their is a lot of value left in the question or answer.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not allowed to delete an "answered" question, but I've flagged it for a moderator.